# Single object 3D viewer for Google Cardboard with Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, google-cardboard

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of the Google Cardboard app’s 'Exhibit' demo. i.e. viewing a single object from all sides - look up and you see under the object, look down and you view it from above, look left or right and you see it from the side, then back.

I've tried a number of things like making the object a child of the camera, and using `transform.LookAt(target);` to keep the camera focused on the object but it isn't working.

New to Unity5 so any help would be very much appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

Using code from a SmoothMouseLook script (http://pastebin.com/vMFkZJAm) this is the closest I've got so far, but it doesn't really work and feels too 'out of control' (the object keeps spinning rather than smoothly turning for inspection) and much less predictable than the 'Exhibit' demo. My guess is that I'm over complicating things. Anyone have any ideas?...

On the Camera(s) ("Main Camera") attach this to keep focused on the object:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class LookAt : MonoBehaviour {
     public Transform target;

     void Update () {
         transform.LookAt(target);
     }
 }
```

On the Object, attach this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class SmoothMouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{   
    /*
     This script is used to average the mouse input over x 
     amount of frames in order to create a smooth mouselook.
     */

    //Mouse look sensitivity    
    public float sensitivityX = 1f;
    public float sensitivityY = 1f;


    //Default mouse sensitivity
    public float defaultSensX = 1f;
    public float defaultSensY = 1f;


    //Minimum angle you can look up
    public float minimumY = -60f;
    public float maximumY = 60f;

    //Minimum angle you can look up
    public float minimumX = -60f;
    public float maximumX = 60f;


    //Number of frames to be averaged, used for smoothing mouselook
    public int frameCounterX = 35;
    public int frameCounterY = 35;


    //Mouse rotation input
    private float rotationX = 0f;
    private float rotationY = 0f;


    //Used to calculate the rotation of this object
    private Quaternion xQuaternion;
    private Quaternion yQuaternion;
    private Quaternion originalRotation;


    //Array of rotations to be averaged
    private List<float> rotArrayX = new List<float> ();
    private List<float> rotArrayY = new List<float> ();


    void Start ()
    {
        //Lock/Hide cursor

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())      
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;


        originalRotation = transform.localRotation;

    }


    void FixedUpdate () 
    {

        //Mouse/Camera Movement Smoothing:    
        //Average rotationX for smooth mouselook

        float rotAverageX = 0f;
        //rotationX += Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.x * sensitivityX;
        //rotationX += Cardboard.SDK.HeadRotation.eulerAngles.x * sensitivityX;
        rotationX += Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Orientation.x * sensitivityX;

        rotationX = ClampAngle (rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);

        //Add the current rotation to the array, at the last position
        rotArrayX.Add (rotationX);

        //Reached max number of steps?  Remove the oldest rotation from the array
        if (rotArrayX.Count >= frameCounterX) {

            rotArrayX.RemoveAt (0);

        }

        //Add all of these rotations together
        for (int i_counterX = 0; i_counterX < rotArrayX.Count; i_counterX++) {
            //Loop through the array
            rotAverageX += rotArrayX[i_counterX];
        }


        //Now divide by the number of rotations by the number of elements to get the average
        rotAverageX /= rotArrayX.Count;


        //Average rotationY, same process as above
        float rotAverageY = 0;
        //rotationY += Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y * sensitivityY;
        //rotationY += Cardboard.SDK.HeadRotation.eulerAngles.y * sensitivityY;
        rotationY += Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Orientation.y * sensitivityY;

        rotationY = ClampAngle (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
        rotArrayY.Add (rotationY);


        if (rotArrayY.Count >= frameCounterY) {
            rotArrayY.RemoveAt (0);
        }


        for (int i_counterY = 0; i_counterY < rotArrayY.Count; i_counterY++) {  
            rotAverageY += rotArrayY[i_counterY];
        }


        rotAverageY /= rotArrayY.Count;


        //Apply and rotate this object
        xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotAverageX, Vector3.up);
        yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotAverageY, Vector3.left);

        transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion * yQuaternion;

    }



    private float ClampAngle (float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360f)  
            angle += 360f;
        if (angle > 360f)
            angle -= 360f;

        return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that particular use case, you don't need a script.  Assuming you are using the CardboardMain prefab, do this:

- Put the object at the origin, and the CardboardMain there too.
- In the Cardboard settings, set Neck Model Scale to 0.
- Open up CardboardMain and select Main Camera under the Head object.
- Set it's Transform Position Z value to a negative value (far enough to see the object).

(You can think of this as the "selfie-stick" camera model.)

Comment: Great stuff. I knew I was over complicating things! Out of interest, where did you go to learn about the Neck Model and other Cardboard settings in Unity? Just getting started and have only found the basic SDK docs (which lack examples) and not much else.

Comment: Well, I cheated a bit -- I helped write the SDK :-)  You are right that the documentation is still quite minimal.

Comment: Thanks @smd Any idea how you could add inertia to the objects rotation so that it slowly comes to a stop when you stop moving your head?